# How can I reopen HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, authentication, httpurlconnection, outputstream

I`ve opened HttpURLConnection connection, opened it and wrote via it:

```
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
httpCon.addRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", getAuthToken());
httpCon.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
httpCon.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding","chunked");
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setChunkedStreamingMode(STREAMING_CHUNK);
OutputStream out   = httpCon.getOutputStream();
```

After some time the authentication token had expired and output stream had been closed. Thus while trying to write I`ve encountered `IOException` 
In order to solve that I tried to reauthenticate and write again:

```
private void ReAuthenticate()
{
   mHttpCon.addRequestProperty("X-Auth-Token", getNewToken());
   mOutputStream = mHttpCon.getOutputStream();
}
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
      try{
         mOutputStream.write(b);
      }
      catch (IOException ex)
      {
          ReAuthenticate();
      }
  }
```

But nothing was written?
What could be wrong? Does all properies of httCon are  saved? for example `httpCon.setDoOutput(true);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have to create a new one for the same `URL`.

However there is TCP connection pooling behind the scenes.